# Big O Complexity

Tags: python-3.x, big-o

I'm trying to understand Big O and thought stepping through a simple program might help.

```
def sum(n):
    k = 0
    j = 0
    while k < n:
        k = k + 1
    while j < n:
        j = j + 1
        k = k + j
    return k
```

k and j are initially assigned the value 0, which counts for 2 assingments, the first while loop performs 1 assignment n times and second while performs 2 assignments n times. So the expression would be 2 + n + 2n.

Because the first two terms in the above expression (2 and n) are constant, they will become insignificant compared to the third term, which multiples n by 2 as n grows. So the Big O for the code would be O(2n).

Is my logic and answer correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I meant "constant", meaning they are not being multiplied or exponentially increased by another value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: So you got `O(3n + 2)` there. Now you ignore the constants and you're left with `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, although we do not say *O(2n)*, but *O(n)* instead.

What *O(n)* means is that the worst case time complexity of your algorithm increases at most linearly, that is it is *eventually* bound by some function of the form `a * n` where *a* is some constant. The actual constant is not relevant for the big-O notation.

To be more technical, I say *eventually* because we are talking about what we call the limiting behaviour of your algorithm, you can think of it as describing the behaviour only for very big inputs.

By example in you algorithm, as `n` grows, we care less and less about the assignations `k = 0` and `j = 0`, they become negligible.

In conclusion, the big-O notation aims to describe *the speed at which the running time grows*, not to describe precisely the what the run time is.

Comment: [Big-O does not mean worst-case](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case).

Comment: I'll try to make it clearer that we talk about limiting behaviour without being too mathy.